# Почтовая рассылка подтверждение регистрации

Tags: php, email, sendmail

Взял хостинг в аренду, купил рекламу сайта и тут сюрприз, узнаю что хостинг не позволяет отправить более 150 писем в час. То есть если более 150 юзеров за час зарегистрируются - хана. Еще не учел что могут восстанавливать пароль и тд. Там где взял хостинг, там же использую услуги колокейшена, стоит сервер на дебиане. Вопрос, никогда так не делал, если я, поднял бы почтовый клиент на своем сервере, как мне средствами php , с сайта на хостинге, отправить письмо именно с сервера на дебиане? Или это не возможно? Подскажите что делать?

Answer (score 2):

Создайте почтовый ящик на стороннем сервисе, например Яндекс. Отправку сообщений с своего сайта делайте через SMTP сервер Яндекса, например, при помощи [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) или подобных.

Comment: Вот пример с яндексом, а что если с яндекса за час отправить 150 писем, там лимита нет?

Comment: Думаю, это вам поможет. В данном случае Яндекс только как пример. http://kingslon.ru/limity-soobshhenij-pochtovyx-serverov/